# How to update in redux with an async function?

Tags: reactjs, redux, web3js

I have a walletReducer that can change depending on the user's actions, for example, when I change my wallet, I have to update its address and balance on the site. I receive this data in an asynchronous function and now the update fails.

```
const walletDefaultState = {
  web3: {},
  account: "",
  balance: "",
};

const CONNECT_BY_METAMASK = "CONNECT_BY_METAMASK";
const WALLET_CONNECT = "WALLET_CONNECT";

export const walletReducer = (state = walletDefaultState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case CONNECT_BY_METAMASK:
      return { ...state, ...action.payload };
    case WALLET_CONNECT:
      return { ...state, cash: state.cash - action.payload };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export const connectByMetaMaskAction = (payload) => ({
  type: CONNECT_BY_METAMASK,
  payload,
});
```

---

```
import Web3 from "web3";
import { connectByMetaMaskAction } from "../../store/walletReducer";

export function createWeb3Listeners() {
  if (window.ethereum) {
    window.ethereum.on("accountsChanged", async () => {
      console.log("accountsChanged");
      const web3 = new Web3(window.ethereum);
      let accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();
      let balance = await web3.eth.getBalance(accounts[0]);
      dispatch(connectByMetaMaskAction({ web3, accounts, balance }));
    });

    window.ethereum.on("chainChanged", () => {
      console.log("chainChanged");
    });

    window.ethereum.on("disconnect", () => {
      console.log("disconnect");
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Why not use the useEffect ? Give account or it's id in your second argument and update your redux there ?

Answer (score 0):

To dispatch the actions after the async, you might need to use the middleware called [redux-thunk-middleware](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk)

Comment: I already have redux-thunk connected, the question is how to pass this data. When I just connect the wallet, I return from the dispatch function, and then I wrap the function itself again in dispatch. How can I act here?